# readfile('filename.exe') and decode base64?

Tags: php, base64

I'm using [php](/questions/tagged/php) in order to stream a file as a download. A part of this uses [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php):

```
<?php
    // headers etc...
    // ...
    readfile('file.exe');
?>
```

This is a binary file, but for various reasons *(that are not relevant to this question)* I need to store this file as base64 *or similar*.

**How do I stream a file with `readfile` that is stored encoded with base64?**

*I guess there are many ways that lead to success here, but I'm looking for the best & most convenient.*

Comment: If the files are reasonably small, don't overdo it and just use `echo base64_decode(file_get_contents($file))`. If the files are relatively large though, you'll want to look into a base64 decoding stream wrapper, which could get a bit more involved.

Comment: I don't need a stream. The file is smaller than 1MB. Will echo(base64_decode(...)) yield a result that is precise? Misplaced bits will result in an exe file that can't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Using stream filters should help:

```
$inFile = 'file.exe';
$outFile = 'php://output';

$inHandle = fopen($inFile, 'r');
$outHandle = fopen($outFile, 'w');

stream_filter_append($inHandle, 'convert.base64-decode');

stream_copy_to_stream($inHandle , $outHandle);
fclose($inHandle );
fclose($outHandle);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file is not too big you can read it using `file_get_contents` and then decode it with `base64_decode`:

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents('file.exe');
    echo base64_decode($content);
```

Comment: Yes, the file is not big at all, I didn't mention that in my question. I will try your method this evening and then I'll let you know if it works :)